# Credit for Dancing Skeleton ClipArt

Tags: copyright, designers

I am wondering if anyone can help me find information on who created the following image. It's an incredibly common piece of online clipart, but its origins and the name of the original artist seem to be somewhat obscure. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: THere is a lots of orphaned works around where its impossible to find owner. Technically if you dont know who the author is and the copyright status of an image then you can not use it.

Comment: What you could do instead is find a rigged Blender model of a skeleton, and pose it yourself.  If you can find one that is has a CC-0 licence, you could use it for anything you want.  I found one [here for free](https://www.blendswap.com/blend/6297).  Why take the risk of copyright infringement!

Comment: Which still might not leave you in the clear if the actual owner pops up and is litigious (https://www.sculpture.org/documents/scmag09/may_09/copy/copy.shtml) but it is on the windy side of the law, as Shakespeare says.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - but then that is probably true for every stock image available on the web today.  Even when purchasing an image we trust that the seller is the actual originator of the work. There's no guarantee they are telling the truth. I still think you would be much less likely to get into trouble if you use a 3D model and modify it yourself to create a unique render. Also perhaps better to avoid copying the pose directly, and get creative instead.

Comment: Looking at the image, I kind of wonder if it was sourced form one of the various medieval *danse macabre* artworks...

Comment: @SeanDuggan, could be, but it looks newer than medieval to me. Maybe from 18-19th century? The oldest danse macabre books have a different style. Anyway it's so widely used that *if* you chose to use it nobody would probably notice.